# How to add {id} lookup at the end of api while using DRF Viewset's action method

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Basically i want {id} of comment at the end of api.
from

```
http://localhost:8000/articles/{id}/comments/
```

to

```
http://localhost:8000/articles/{id}/comments/{id}/
```

```
class ArticlesViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet
):
    queryset = Articles.objects.order_by("-created")
    serializer_class = ArticlesSerializer

    @action(methods=["delete"], detail=True)
    def comments(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
```

urls.py

```
v1_router = routers.DefaultRouter()
v1_router.register(r"articles", ArticleViewSet)

urlpatterns = [path("v1/", include(v1_router.urls))]
```

how to make url as described above?

Comment: could you share your `urls.py` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For someone who is still interested to know how i resolved this issue was,

```
    @action(
        detail=True,
        methods=["post"],
        url_path="comments/(?P<comment_id>[^/.]+)",
    )
    def comments(self, request, comment_id):
        # you can continue here with rest of the code
```

Now you can have api like

```
http://localhost:8000/articles/{id}/comments/{id}/
```